# How do I progress in Ars Magica 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I took with my first skill points "Self" and "Regenerate" and "Projectile". Now I can make only 2 spells - "Self Regenerate" & "Projectile Regenerate" - which I both can't cast. The first uses 270 Mana, the second uses 540 mana - but I have only 100.

How can I progress further? I don't have any points to unlock other spells and I can't cast my current ones because I don't have the mana - thus I can't progress.

How do I level up so I can unlock more points?

Comment: By casting spells. Try only making a projectile spell with nothing on it and only cast it and it will increase your level...

Comment: I didn't know that you could do a projectile that does nothing, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can stop casting the spell at a higher caster ability.  Press the C button to lower the mana cost (and also the effectiveness, but it's worth it).

Answer (score 1):

it looks like I found my anwer here: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2028696-ars-magica-2-162164-version-102b-updated-oct-27/page__st__1880#entry27039682

the /respec command should does the trick. I tried it out and speced to projectile, phsical. Now I can cast the spell and gained several level.